# Hahn-Banach theorem geometric form complex case

Tags: functional-analysis

Where can I find the proof of this version of  Hahn-Banach theorem  :

Let $X$ be a (complex) locally convex space, and $A,B\subset X$ disjoint, nonempty, convex, with $A$ compact and $B$ closed. Then there exists a continuous linear functional $\varphi :X\rightarrow \mathbb C$ and $c,d\in\mathbb R$ with

$Re\varphi(w) \gt c \gt d \gt Re\varphi(v),   v\in A,  w\in B.$

Comment: Hint: A complex vector space is, in particular, a real vector space.  Given a real-linear functional $\psi$, there exists a complex-linear $\phi$ such that $\psi(w) = \mathrm{Re}\;\phi(w)$ for all $w$.  From the formula you get when you do this, you see that if $\psi$ is continuous then so is $\phi$.

Comment: thanks, I get it